# Type hinting overriden __new__ in a subclass of a generic class

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Consider the following:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")

class A():
    pass

class B(A, Generic[T]): 
    def __new__(cls, x: T):
        return super().__new__(cls)

class C(B[T]): 
    def __new__(cls, x: T):
        return super().__new__(cls, x)
```

On the last line, mypy raises the following errors:

```
# Argument 1 to "__new__" of "B" has incompatible type "type[C[T]]"; expected "type[B[T]]"  [arg-type]
# Argument 2 to "__new__" of "B" has incompatible type "T"; expected "T"  [arg-type]
```

- Overriding `__new__` this way seems normal, apart from the generics. I know `type[C]` is compatible with `type[B]`, so why is this not the case with `type[C[T]]` and `type[B[T]]` ? I don't think this has anything to do with variance (though I did try).
- I don't understand the second error at all

I haven't found any similar SO questions, and read through https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html to no avail.

EDIT: it could also be linked to this: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides, as I'm overriding `__new__` with an argument type that is probably more specific (even though I didn't manual typehint it), but it's not the same error and seems necessary for `__new__` to work correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, there’s 2 generic types in your `__new__`, one of them implicit (`cls: type[typing.Self]`), but `T` cannot be declared separately from `Self`. Long story short, you can’t statically type this until higher-kinded types are supported.